(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ASP.NET Core 8.0.1
This error occurred when I was trying to connect to the database

This error occurs when I give a command (update database):
I have downloaded the packages:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Connection to SQL Server:


Try adding ;TrustServerCertificate=true to your connection string .....

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.


A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
error occurred during the login process.(provider: SSL Provider,
error: 0- The certificate chain was issued (provider: Named Pipes
Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
ASP.NET Core 8.0.1

According to your error message which indicating, the server might be using a self-signed certificate, which it created itself. Since it wasn't issued by a trusted CA, your device doesn't recognize it as legitimate. This is common in testing environments. Thus,the bottom line is, your device is saying, "I connected to the server, but I can't trust its identity because the certificate isn't from a reliable source."
In order to fix your issue you should set the TrustServerCertificate to true. Because, when TrustServerCertificate is set to true and encryption is turned on, the encryption level specified on the server will be used even if Encrypt is set to false in the connection string. The connection will fail otherwise which @marc_s already commented.
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\ServrerName;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 },


Note: Please refer to this official document if you want to study more.
